# array in node js behaves odd

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm using node js to create a multi player game website. so every time a socket is connected I  add that socket in an array like this

```
var users = [];
var games = [];
var joinKey = [];
var key = 0;
var usersKey = 101;
var gamesKey = 201;

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        console.log('connect');
        var clientId = usersKey;
        socket.clientId = clientId;
        users[usersKey] = socket;
        usersKey++;
        socket.emit('getClientId', clientId);
        console.log(socket.clientId + ' connected');
        console.log('Total users: ' + users.length);
    });
```

here total users shows 102 as user key is 101 and it automatically tales blank values from 0 to 100. this is not normal i guess. also if I retrieve the socket from other array using index, it is undefined if the index is string, like 'g201'

```
socket.on('createNewGame', function(){
        var game = [];
        var clientId = socket.clientId;
        game[clientId] = socket;
        console.log(game);
        var gameId = 'g' + gamesKey;
        gamesKey++;
        games[gameId] = game;
        console.log('Total Games: ' + games.length)
        socket.gameId = gameId;

        var publicKey = ++key;
        joinKey[publicKey] = gameId;

        socket.emit('gameCreated', publicKey);
    });
```

I'm not getting how to insert and fetch if this is the behavior of array here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first point:

An array uses numerical indices running from 0.

When you manually place a value in at 101 it will fill the rest of the values in since it has to run from 0, these will be padded with undefined. (*as per Andrew Barretts comment*)

To answer your second point:

If you need to have an "associate array" or at least what people refer to as an associative array then you should use objects.

```
game= new Object();
game["g1"]=...
game["g25"]=...
...
```

Comment: It's probably clearer to say, "The array gets padded with undefined"

Comment: And will I be able to retrieve them using obj = game['g232'] ??